# Visual Basic: Cannot pass custom object to asmx web service, whats wrong?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to pass a custom object to an asmx web service without avail. I have a dll containing the class referenced in my main project, as well as in the web service project.

This line of code (**CompleteDataTransport** is a DataSyncTransport object):

```
result = TestService.WholeDataUpload(10, CompleteDataTransport, AttachmentHelper.Authenticate("12345678"))
```

Throws the error: Value of type DataSyncTransport cannot be converted to DataOnDataTables.

I Googled around the error, and I came with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947680/passing-custom-objects-to-a-web-service) SO question that basically says the the object must be serializable in order to can pass it to the service.

I did it. Here's is my class:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable()>
<XmlRoot("DataSyncTransport")>
Public Class DataSyncTransport

    <XmlElement("WholeData")>
    Property WholeData As New List(Of DataOnDataTables)

End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class DataOnDataTables

    <XmlElement("IdKey")>
    Property IdKey As String

    <XmlElement("ColumnsValidation")>
    Property ColumnsValidation As String

    <XmlElement("TableName")>
    Property TableName As String

    <XmlElement("DataTableForUpload")>
    Property DataTableForUpload As New DataTable

End Class
```

And here is the web service method:

```
Public Function WholeDataUpload(ByVal appId As Integer, ByVal 
                DataSyncTransport As DataSyncTransport, ByVal token As String) As String

    Dim _result As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As DataOnDataTables In DataSyncTransport.WholeData()
        Try
            _result = Upload(appId, item.TableName, item.ColumnsValidation, 
                      item.DataTableForUpload, token)
        Catch ex As Exception
            _result = ex.Message
        End Try
    Next

    Return _result

End Function
```

What I'm doing wrong?? Please help.

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you update the web service reference in the client project?

Comment: Hi Steven. I updated the web service reference via right click -> Update Service Reference and nothing happens. Same error on client "Value of type DataSyncTransport cannot be converted to DataOnDataTables(). The error doesn't have any sense!

Comment: When it updates the web reference, is it pointing at the right URL?

Comment: It points to http://localhost:8080/Sync.asmx. The service is not running when I update the reference because both projects, client and service, run at the same time. They are in the same solution. So I'll say... yes, it is pointing to the right URL.

Comment: Are you able to put a break-point in the web method and does the break-point get hit?  If so, can you step through all of the code on in the web method without exception?

Comment: You didn't mark DataOnDataTables as serializable. Try that.

Comment: I have the error the I mentioned on my client and I cannot run the application. However if I change my web service to expect a simple string, I can run the application and the breakpoint get hit in the web service.

Comment: You might also need to remove the `XmlRoot()` attribute for DataOnDataTables, because it is not always the root element.

Comment: @tgolisch I edited my question. I did marked DataOnDataTables as Serializable.  I also removed XMLRoot() from DataOnDataTables. No changes. Same error :(

Comment: Something looks out-of-place with your iterator for `DataSyncTransport.WholeData()` It looks like it is using the type instead of the variable. Have you tried renaming the variable so it doesn't have the same name as the type?